# How to make api get requests from dukascopy?

Tags: api, get

I have an api key but i'm not sure on how to make an get request using their api.
The documentation is a bit vague on how to format the url, any help is appreciated!

Documentation:
https://www.dukascopy.com/trading-tools/api/documentation/quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the API you just need to append your key in the URL like,

```
https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/?path=api/lastOneMinuteCandles&key={you_api_key}
```

Another example,

[image]

```
https://freeserv.dukascopy.com/2.0/?path=api/currentPrices&key={api_key}&instruments=EUR/USD,USD/JPY
```

You can use Postman, and should see some values come back (since my key is not valid, I got 401).

[image]